# Delete Gravity Forms file attachments after submission but keep all other fields?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

OK, we have a job submission form on the site where users need to complete the form and attach resume and cover letter. For privacy reasons, we do not want to keep the resumes and cover letters on the server, so what we've been doing is send emails with form submission, attach resume and cover letter, and then completely delete the submission.

This is the code we've been using and everything works the way it should.

```
/**
 *
 * Target submissions from form ID  2.
 *
 * Change gform_after_submission_2 to reflect your target form ID, 
 * or use gform_after_submission to target all forms.
 * 
 */

add_action( 'gform_after_submission_2', 'remove_form_entry' );
function remove_form_entry( $entry ) {
    GFAPI::delete_entry( $entry['id'] );
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to keep the form entries but just delete the attachments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just wrote the function, tested and it works fine to delete resume file.
You can add more code same way for cover letters.

```
add_filter( 'gform_after_submission_2', 'remove_form_entry', 10, 2 );
function remove_form_entry( $entry, $form  ) {
     global $wpdb;
 
    $lead_id = $entry['id'];
    
    $meta_key = 1; //it is the uploads field id.
    
    $entry_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'gf_entry_meta'; //meta table of gravity forms
    
    $get_resume_file_statement = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$entry_table` WHERE  `meta_key` = %d AND `entry_id` = %d", $meta_key, $lead_id); 
    $meta_values_of_resume_file = $wpdb->get_col( $get_resume_file_statement ); // get uploaded csv file url
     
    $resume_url = explode('uploads', $meta_values_of_resume_file [0]); //get file url after uploads folder. It returns file url like http://localhost/g2a/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/3-dbbe121585c30ed9e49ec2a6803270b0/2021/07/89636498_188586552577282_8867025936109797376_n.jpg
    
    $resume_file_name = end($resume_url ); //get file url after uploads folder. value like /gravity_forms/3-dbbe121585c30ed9e49ec2a6803270b0/2021/07/89636498_188586552577282_8867025936109797376_n.jpg

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); //uploads dir
    
    $full_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . $resume_file_name; //get full path of file
    wp_delete_file( $full_path ); //delete the file
    //update entry meta field value here or delete the entry meta.
}
```

Comment: Well, that just solves it! Amazing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tested everything, got notification email, got attachments in the email. the entry is stored in the DB but the attachments are deleted. Love it!